# performance drop and strange GC behaviour after one hour in jboss 5.0.1GA

Tags: performance, memory, jboss, garbage-collection

We upgraded our software from jboss 4.0.5GA to 5.0.1GA and noticed that after one hour or so (or 90 minutes in some cases) performance drops dramatically.

At the same moment, the garbage collector logs show minor garbage collection times jumping from 0.01s to ~1.5s, with the amount of the heap being cleared each time reducing from ~400MB before to ~300MB after.  (see GC viewer graph 1)

[image: gc graph]

We think these are both symptoms of the the same underlying root cause.

jvm settings are:

```
-server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:NewSize=384m -XX:MaxNewSize=384m 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=11 -XX:PermSize=80m -verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-Djava.awt.headless=TRUE -DUseSunHttpHandler=TRUE 
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=25000 
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=50000 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dvzzv.log.dir=${ercorebatch.log.dir} -Xloggc:${ercorebatch.log.dir}/gc.log  
-Duser.language=it -Duser.region=IT -Duser.country=IT -DVFjavaWL=er.core.it
```

The production environment is T5220 or T2000 hardware, with 32 bit SPARC, running a Solaris 10 virtual machine. jboss 5.0.1.GA, java 1.6.0_17

We set up a test environment consisting of 2 identical boxes, running the same software but one using jboss 4.0.5GA and one using jboss 5.0.1.GA.  They are VMWare VMs running on a HP ProLiant DL560 Gen8 with 4 x 2.2GHz Intel Xeon CPU E5-4620 and 64GB RAM.  Guest VMs are 4 vCPU, 4096MB RAM, CentOS 6.4.

We found that we could easily reproduce the problem in our environment.  The box which was running on 4.0.5 ran fine, but on jboss 5.0.1GA we saw the same strange GC behaviour.  Performance can't easily be tested in our environment since we don't have the same amount of load as production.

We don't think it's a memory leak, since after each major GC, the used heap size returns to the same size:

[image]

Analysing heap dumps taken pre- and post-apocalypse, we discovered the number of the following objects was different:

`org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.file.FileSystemContext`

during the first hour, there are about 8 of them, and after the apocalypse hits, we see between 100 and 800.

Other than that, the heap dumps look quite similar, and the top objects are either java or jboss objects (ie no application classes)

Setting `-Djboss.vfs.forceVfsJar=true` on our test environment fixed the problem (i.e. the strange GC behaviour disappeared) but when applied in production, both the strange GC pattern and the performance problem remained - although the GC times did not increase so much (to 0.3 seconds rather than 1.5 seconds).

In our test environment, we then deployed the same software in jboss 5.1.0 and found the same behaviour as with 5.0.1.

So the conclusions at this point are that there is something happening in jboss 5.x around the 60 / 90 minute mark which has an impact on both garbage collection and performance.

**UPDATE:**

We tried upgrading the web services stack to jbossws-native-3.3.1, which fixed the problem in our test environment. However, when deploying to the next test environment (closer to the production environment), the problem was still there (albeit reduced).

**UPDATE:**

We have resolved this by setting jboss.vfs.cache.TimedPolicyCaching.lifetime to a very large number equivalent to many years.

This feels like a workaround for a bug in jboss.  The default cache lifetime is 30 minutes (see org.jboss.util.TimedCachePolicy), and we saw problems after either 60 or 90 minutes.

The VFS cache implementation is CombinedVFSCache and I think it's using a TimedVFSCache underneath.

It seems like a better fix would be to change the cache implementation to a permanent cache, but we've wasted enough time on this problem and our workaround will have to do.

Comment: Based on your question, I assume you've seen [this bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7284) which affects both 5.0.1 and 5.1.0GA? Is there a reason why you can't use 5.1.2? It would be interesting to see thread dumps "post-apocalypse" to see if there is another cause to the prod slowdown. There may have been two original causes.

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes we saw that bug which is why we tried the vfs jvm option, which didn't work. I believe 5.1.2 is not free for commercial use, which means we can't use it in the same way that we can use 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to determine the root cause of this problem just looking at the  Gc graphs. So how does the stacks looks like when this happens? Is there any hyperactive threads? Is there any nasty threads creating a huge pile of objects forcing the garbage collector to work as hell to get rid of them? I think that more analysis must be performed to determine the root cause of the problem.